# Is there a function or arrangement that returns the penultimate line of a txt file?

Tags: file, perl

There are three or more lines that the document brings, that is the size of the list
`doc03053220190606125901(1).txt.total.txt`

```
Tamafo total: 512 MB
Total 43046✔
Total 14758
```

`doc05889820190606122032(2).txt.total.txt`

```
Tamano total: 1.0 GB
Total 156253✔
, Total 761273
```

of the txt documents I want to print only line one before the last

I tried to apply the pop function without the push function to run again pop and bring me the penultimate line
or at the time of printing I give an example

---

```
my @arreglo = $row;
pop @arreglo "$files\n"
print @arreglo[-1]"\n"; 

foreach $filename (@FILES) {

    ## muestra el contenido de la variable
    print $filename, "\n"; 
    ## abre el archivo o manda una excepcion 
    open(my $file, '<', $filename) 
        or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    while (my $row = <$file>) {

        chomp $row;   
        print ("$row\n");

    }
```

Comment: Maybe good to post on the Spanish version of stack overflow.

Comment: Please edit and translate to English, or post to es.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I still have no clue what the beginning means ... ?  Since I can't answer until this gets reopened (if it does), here's couple of ways: (1) Read the whole file, putting lines in an array, and print `$lines[-2]` (one before last) (2) If the file is too big for this, first read through it to count lines and then read again where now you'll know which line to print.  If it bothers you to make two passes -- or the file is _really_ large and it's slow -- then you can record (some) positions (`pos`) in the file while counting lines and then `seek` suitably instead of making the second full pass.

Comment: @gama larios, If it can be a large file, use [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards). If it's a small file, you could also read the entire file into memory (`my @lines = <>; $lines[-2]`).

Comment: @zdim, I strongly believe those are the contents of the file, in which case the files appear to contain size information about something. I don't really see how it could be anything else. Thus the edit.

Comment: @zdim, Another problem for another day :) In theory, it could still work without decoding+encoding because the 8-bit clean nature of reading and writing.

Comment: @zdim, The OP Seems to have confirmed this ("There are three or more lines that the document brings" probably means "the files have three or more lines").

Comment: of the files at the beginning I just want the line before the last one to be returned to me, in the code I put in it I only list it

Comment: I just want to print the line that is patted

Comment: I provided solutions in my first comment.

Comment: ikegami, My @lines = <>; $lines[-2] I insert this part of the code inside the while or outside

Comment: @gamalarios  You don't need the `while` for that.  The `<>` is a bit magical -- it opens files passed to the program on the command line and reads from them, and since you assign it to an array it will read and return _all_ lines.  So after `my @lines = <>;` the `@lines` array has all lines from all files submitted to the program on the command line. So if you invoked it as `script.pl filename` then `@lines` has all lines from file `filename` (newlines included)

Comment: Well, they can't actually use `<>` here, so it would actually be `<$file>` in this situation (although `$fh` would be a better name than the misnamed `$file`). I was giving a short generic answer and leaving the detailsto the OP

Comment: @gamalarios My previous comment is on use of `<>`.  But if you have names of multiple files (in an array like your `@FILES`) which you need to open and process individually then you can't use `<>`.  Instead, as you open a file (with a filehandle, say, `$fh`) you do `my @lines = <$fh>;` and now `@lines` has lines from the file (opened with `$fh`), etc.  (That `$file` is a misleading name for a variable that is in fact a _filehandle_.  It looks like a filename)

Comment: So. like `for my $file (@files) { open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; my @lines = <$fh>; print $lines[-2]; }`. Remember that each element of `@lines` ends with a newline.

Comment: tie my @lineas, 'Tie::File', $filename or die "ERROR: $!\n";
while (my $row = <$lineas[-2]>) This is how my line is in the while

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, Regards !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gama, there is no need for a complex script here.  The Unix tail command will do it for you.

```
@last_two_lines = `tail -n2 $filename`;
print $last_two_lines[0];
```

Comment: This assumes that the `tail` command is available. It's not likely to work on Windows, for example. Also, it doesn't handle the case where input is shorter than 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement: Print the second to last line of input.

The obvious solution is to slurp all of input into an array, but if the input is too large that's going to waste memory. You should also handle the case where input is less than two lines.

My solution: Keep an array that holds just the last two lines. You won't know that you've seen the second to last line until you've reached the end of the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @last2 = ();
while (<>) {
    if (scalar @last2 >= 2) {
        shift @last2;
    }
    push @last2, $_;
}
if (scalar @last2 >= 2) {
    print $last2[-2];
}
else {
    die "Not enough input\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't need a call to `scalar` since in the "scalar context" (here set by `>=`) an array is evaluated to its size and that is then used; so just `@last2 >= 2`

Comment: @zdim: True, it's not needed, but this is a case where I like to be more explicit.